# I need something like CRON but for IIS 8.5/PHP on Windows Server 2012R2

Tags: php, windows, iis, cron

This PHP script has to run every twenty two seconds. How can I pull this off without CRON on a Linux box?

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\4dalulz.com\webcam_network\grabimage_cam_18_331103_-64_795038_17z.php
```

Comment: Can you explain the 22 seconds?  From your filename it looks like you are getting a screen capture of a webcam.  Maybe there is a more efficient way to capture that data if you give us some more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a basic windows hosting account or is this a standalone box that you have admin access to?  If it is a box that you have admin rights to then in windows you can use Task Scheduler, or AT which is a lightweight system like cron.  Here is Microsofts link on AT and how to use it http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/313565

If you have shared windows hosting then it gets more complicated.  You might want to configure an outside service to request a web-accessible script on your schedule to perform your actions.  Something like https://www.setcronjob.com/

Comment: I think that both `at` and `cron` can run at most every minute - there's no way I can think of to use them to run something every 22 seconds, if that's what the requirement is. The only thing I can come up with is something like a daemon, that runs constantly - it can call the program and then sleep for 22 seconds; but even that will have issues, as you can't guarantee that it won't sleep for longer.